# Create NSString for data returned

Tags: ios, objective-c

The following code retrieves a logged in user's data from my Drupal database:

**.m**

```
   DIOSSession *session = [DIOSSession sharedSession];

   [session user];
```

**The data appears in the XCode console like so:**

```
{"uid":"1","name":"Laura"}
```

That being said, how do I turn the UID returned into a string I can actually use?

**E.g.** I need to have the logged in UID appear in this line where @"1" currently is, as I don't always want to display details for "user 1", I want to display details for the logged in user:

**.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDictionary *entityData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"] forKey:@"uid"];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! For those wondering, I ended up retrieving the uid with:

**.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *userid;
```

**.m**

```
    DIOSSession *session = [DIOSSession sharedSession];

    [session user];

    self.userid = [[session user] objectForKey:@"uid"];
```

Comment: u can also try  dictionary[@"uid"]